# android - listview - blocksDescendants and avoid highlighting sub elements

Tags: android, listview, row, highlight

To be able to select the item (the row) AND sub items on the row, I use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. And I'm using the `onItemSelect`event....

I as well use a custom background for my row.

Now the problem is, when I touch a row, the checkbox get's it's selected background as well (the blue default background, when you select a checkbox), how do I avoid this? I only want the row itself to adjust it's background to the item state, when I touch the row.

I'm using following row layout as a row in a listview in an adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@drawable/list_gradient"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSelected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDayName"
    style="@style/text_list_info_big"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbSelected"
    android:text="Tag" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/grabber" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/s"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDayName"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCount"
        style="@style/text_list_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInfo"
        style="@style/text_list_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvInfo2"
        style="@style/text_list_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

PS: I know I could handle the `onClick` event of the row and the sub items in my adapter instead of using `onItemClick`, but I'm using the DragAndSortList view and doing it that way does not work with the drag&drop there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Overriding SetPressed of the row didn't work.

Now I'm using following RelativeLayout and that's solving my problem:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class UnpressableRL extends RelativeLayout
{
    public UnpressableRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void  dispatchSetPressed(boolean pressed) {
        // avoid handing on the event to the child views
     }
}
```